# How to show that value is conserved along geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry

Let's have the motion of charged particle in a field of [Reissner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)-type black hole.
The equation of motion looks like
$$
\frac{d^{2}x^{\mu}}{d \tau^{2}} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d \tau}\frac{dx^{\lambda}}{d \tau} = \frac{q}{m}F^{\mu}_{\quad \nu} \frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}.
$$
How to show that value
$$
E = m\left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}}\right)\frac{dt}{d\tau} + \frac{qQ}{r}
$$ 
is conserved along geodesics, $u^{\mu}D_{\mu} E = 0$?

The first step, maybe, must be the attention to find the $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$. But what to do after that? It doesn't seems like convolution $\varepsilon_{\mu}u^{\mu}$ or to $u_{\mu}u^{\mu}$, where $u^{\mu}$ is the 4-speed. So what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose in classical mechanics, I told you that $\ddot{x} = \frac{F}{m}$, where $F$ is a conservative force. You would have no trouble finding a conserved value along the trajectory (I hope). What you need, therefore, is to use the GR version of the work-kinetic-energy theorem. If I were in a hurry, I would start with the Lagrangian that gives the EOM and then derive the Hamiltonian :)

Also, iirc, $u^\mu D_\mu \equiv \frac{d}{d\tau}$, if $\tau$ is affine.

Finally, you could just write the geodesic equation out in components (at least, the interesting ones that don't vanish, e.g., $\ddot{x}$ and $\ddot{t}$) and then write $\dot{E}$ in terms of $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{t}$. This is probably the "low level" way of doing the problem, although it might be quicker.

Comment: Thank you! I absolutely forgot about $u^{\mu}D_{\mu} = \frac{d}{d\tau}$. It works, because in that case $u^{\mu}D_{\mu}E$ implies the geodesic equation for t.

Comment: Care to write that out for posterity? (If it's only a line or two?)

Comment: $$
E = Am\frac{dt}{d\tau} + \frac{Qq}{r}, \quad A = 1 - \frac{2M}{r} + \frac{Q^{2}}{r^{2}},
$$
$$
\frac{dE}{d\tau} = m\frac{dA}{d \tau} \frac{dt}{d\tau} + mA\frac{d^{2}t}{d\tau^{2}} - \frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\frac{dr}{d\tau} = mA' \frac{dr}{d\tau} \frac{dt}{d\tau} + mA\frac{d^{2}t}{d\tau^{2}} - \frac{qQ}{r^{2}}\frac{dr}{d\tau} = 0.
$$